# How to keep toogleClass() state on page refresh or moving to another HTML subsite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with couple subpages in .html. On every page there is two "buttons" for language change. Is there any solution, that help me keep currently selected language after a page refresh or moving to another subsite?

This is my code:

```
    // Language icons //
  var polIco = $('.language_ico_container').find('img').first();
  var engIco = $('.language_ico_container').find('img').last();

  engIco.toggleClass('transparency');

  function checkTransparency() {
    engIco.click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('transparency');
      if (engIco.hasClass('transparency')) {
        polIco.removeClass('transparency');
      } else {
        polIco.addClass('transparency');
      }
    });
    polIco.click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('transparency');
      if (polIco.hasClass('transparency')) {
        engIco.removeClass('transparency');
      } else {
        engIco.addClass('transparency');
      }
    });
  };
  // Call function checking transparency in language icons //
  checkTransparency();

  // English & Polish content selection //
  var languagePL = $('.pl');
  var languageEN = $('.eng');

  languageEN.toggleClass('hidden');

  function changeLanguage() {
    engIco.click(function () {
      languageEN.toggleClass('hidden');
      languagePL.toggleClass('hidden');
    });

    polIco.click(function () {
      languageEN.toggleClass('hidden');
      languagePL.toggleClass('hidden');
    });
  };
  // Call function changing content language
  changeLanguage();
```

And CSS classes:

```
    .hidden {
    display: none;
}

    .transparency {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: So you have content for multiple languages in one document? That is bad already, in regard to search engines, users being able to share what they see with others, etc. You should really consider switching to a system that provides the different language versions of the content under different URLs.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to keep using this sub-optimal system, then you will have to store the information somewhere, so that JS will have access to it on the “next page” - so that usually means cookies, or localstorage/sessionstorage. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+save+state+for+next+page should give you enough hints to start.

Comment: Let's say it's just for practice for now ;) I will keep that in mind in future projects.

Comment: I am familiar with cookies and localStorage, but I can't figure out how to implement this solutions to my case. My problem is - what to do with toggleClass after using one of them, should i keep it (but then every subsite will execute my JS code with toggleClass anyway) or is there other way to add and remove classes with local storage?

Comment: _“or is there other way to add and remove classes with local storage?”_ - not directly, those two things have little to do with each other. You need to store the info which of the relevant elements have what class, and then you have to _set_ those classes on the next page when it gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage can be a solution  is used to save data across browser sessions..
You can implement your classes with session storage, every time you set transparency class you can add it to the local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('class','transparency');
```

when you remove the class you can also remove it from the local storage

```
 localStorage.removeItem('class');
```

And when the page is refreshed you can set the class from the localStorage

```
localStorage.getItem('class');
```

Comment: Still don't know how to use it in my case. Should I create a function that contains "localStorage.setItem('class','transparency')" and call it on button click? 
And should I define which language must be hidden on page load or leave it to localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Its just an instant idea on which you can build own solution:

```
$.fn.toggleTransparency = function () {
  if (localStorage[this] === undefined) {
    localStorage[this] = true
  } else {
    localStorage[this] = !localStorage[this]
  }
  localStorage[this]
    ? this.addClass('transparency')
    : this.removeClass('transparency')
}

// Usage:
$(selector).toggleTransparency()
```

Comment: You mean: 

$.fn.toggleTransparency = function () {
    localStorage[this] = !!this
    localStorage[this]
      ? this.addClass('transparency')
      : this.removeClass('transparency')
  }
  
  // Usage:
  engIco.toggleTransparency();

This toggling my transparency class, but reset after refresh or moving subpages. 
Did I something wrong?

Comment: As I said, it was an instant idea. I dont know if it works. Just create own, complete solution based on this idea.

Comment: Sure thing, Thanks for tips ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this solution:

```
var polIco = $('.language_ico_container').find('img').first();
  var engIco = $('.language_ico_container').find('img').last();

    // English content hidden on load //

  engIco.addClass(localStorage.added);

  engIco.on('click', function() {
    switchEngTransparency();
  });

  function switchEngTransparency() {
    if (localStorage.added != 'transparency') {
      engIco.addClass('transparency', true);
      localStorage.added = 'transparency';
    } else {
      engIco.addClass('transparency', false);
      localStorage.added = '';
    }
  };

  function deactivateOppositeIcon() {
    if (!engIco.hasClass('transparency')) {
      polIco.addClass('transparency');
    } else {
      polIco.removeClass('transparency');
    }
  };

  deactivateOppositeIcon();

.transparency {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But the problem is - when i click on engIco the transparency is changing only after refreshing site or moving to another subsite. It's not changing immediately. Any ideas how to fix it?